# how can i show GridView when i click an item from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.AutoPostBack = true;
    Class1 cc = new Class1();
    string k = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    DataTable l = cc.table1(k);
    GridView g = new GridView();
    g.DataSource = l;
    g.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yes you can show it but it must exist on the page's control-collection and you haven't aded it. Instead declare it on the aspx markup. You can make the `GridView` visible instead.

Comment: You are creating Gridview dynamically.You have to have a place holder.And add this gridview control there.But remember it will need to let recreate dynamic control on each postback.Better is to have  declred Gridview in your markup and you should bind and play with it's visibility from this event

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AutoPostBack=true` `before` `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` to make it effective. DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged will never get fired if AutoPostBack is not set to true before.

You can set `AutoPostBack=true` at design time on in page_load event.